# Set my own question as solved

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, self-answer

I have this request is because I have a few questions which did not get proper answers. and later I found out the answer myself. but when I come back to Stack Overflow, I can not flag my own question as solved.

I think we need some feature like this, so everybody can eliminate their own questions from unanswered list, besides, doing so also increases our own acceptance rate.

Comment: By "please execute me", do you mean "run me like a program" or "kill me"?

Comment: answer your own question with a reasonable answer and accept that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have that feature already, it's called answering your own question and then accepting that answer (with the big green tick to the side of the answer).

There's absolutely nothing wrong with doing that but you may want to check first if anyone else has given the same answer since:

1. Self-accepted answers don't rise to the top like normal accepted answers.
2. You get no rep (although you should be answering to improve the site rather than gain rep).

Comment: ok, thanks. but wouldn't clicking a button to flag is faster.

Comment: @bingjie2680: The point isn't to be fast, the point is to add value! If you just mark it as solved, nobody else learns anything. If you add your solution and then mark it as correct, others can solve their problem. If you expect to learn and gain from the community, it's good conduct to also give a little back. It's the least you can do.